# I have accidentally created an environment

Tags: kubuntu, syslinux

I have accidentally created an environment and now it gives me another new partition. How can I delete that partition?As you can see in the picture, I want to delete this partitions which I accidentally created using new environment command on terminal [image]

Comment: Can you describe *exactly* what you did? What is the exact command that you used?  What kind of environment are you talking about? Your screenshot shows only one volume and that's the one where Ubuntu is installed. It's not clear what is the problem.

Comment: No my ubuntu isn't installed in this volume, actually I was setting up Odoo on my ubuntu and I mistakenly entered the command, and suddenly this new volume came in when I turn on my laptop again. Now I forgot that command

Comment: @MuhammadAamirKhan you can check it using `history`

Comment: thank you I found that command ,

Comment: sudo useradd -m -d /opt/odoo15 -U -r -s /bin/bash odoo15      ( I am sure that was the command )

Comment: sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s odoo15"   ( and then I wrote this command)